# INIntent `setImage` make runtime crash in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, sirishortcuts, swift5, swift-keypath

I've used `INIntent` object since Siri shortcut is added. For that I made an intent definition and it generated a `INIntent` object automatically.

```
@available(iOS 12.0, watchOS 5.0, *)
@objc(SpotConditionIntent)
public class SpotConditionIntent: INIntent {

    @NSManaged public var spotId: String?
    @NSManaged public var spotName: String?

}
```

To customize the Siri shortcut voice record screen, I added a convenience initializer. It was basically to add `suggestedInvocationPhrase` and the top icon image.

```
@available(iOS 12, *)
extension SpotConditionIntent {
    convenience init(spotId: String, spotName: String) {
        self.init()
        self.spotId = spotId
        self.spotName = spotName
        self.suggestedInvocationPhrase = "\(NSLocalizedString("how_are_waves_text", comment: "How are the waves at")) \(spotName)?"
        if let uiimage = UIImage(named: "check-surf-icon"), let data = uiimage.pngData() {
            let inImage = INImage(imageData: data)
            setImage(inImage, forParameterNamed: \.spotName)
        }
    }
}
```

Today, I tried to convert the entire project to Swift 5 and there was no issue on building. (There was no actual change in the code.) However it crashes on runtime with very weird message.

> Thread 1: Fatal error: could not detangle key path type from `XXXX9SpotConditionIntentCXD`

and it pointed the `setImage(inImage, forParameterNamed: \.spotName)`.

I just found that the `setImage(,forParameterNamed)` doesn't exist in the documentation.

[image]

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/inintent

Seems like I need to use `func keyImage() -> INImage?` which is added in iOS 12.

But I have no idea why it works in Swift 4.X and can't find any documentation for the deprecation. Anyone knows about this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I checked...

The two methods are available in Objective-C.

[- imageForParameterNamed:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/inintent/2976222-imageforparameternamed?language=objc)

[- setImage:forParameterNamed:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/inintent/2976224-setimage?language=objc)

And the generated interface for these methods shown as...

```
// Set an image associated with a parameter on the receiver. This image will be used in display of the receiver throughout the system.
@available(iOS 12.0, *)
open func __setImage(_ image: INImage?, forParameterNamed parameterName: String)

@available(iOS 12.0, *)
open func __image(forParameterNamed parameterName: String) -> INImage?
```

The docs or code suggestion of Xcode will not show you these, but you can use them in Swift 5 code:

```
    intent.__setImage(image, forParameterNamed: "spotName")
```

Though, using underscore-leaded methods may be taken as using private APIs when submitting your app to App Store.

This sort of things sometimes happens when Apple is *swiftifying* some methods and not completed yet.

As for now, what you can do are...

- Send a bug report to Apple, immediately
- Write an Objective-C wrapper for these methods and import it into Swift

or

- Delay submitting your up until new SDK with this issue fixed will be provided
  (Can be years...)

Comment: It is super interesting. It was __setImage in a certain version of iOS12 beta, but Apple changed it to setImage at the gold version.